# How Can I Make A Div Show From Clicking An Entity/OBJ in Aframe Scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

Im having an issue with my code here. Im still pretty new to Javascript so I may be making a noobie mistake. What Im trying to accomplish is to be able to click the red tree on the globe in my example and a red div box should pop up. I feel like I've done everything right but I keep receiving an error message in my console of *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"* I setup a Glitch with my example code. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Big thanks in advance!

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/57349026-d43e-4466-87f0-b793c7a89c5f

Comment: I would recommend you post the code you're having problem with here on stackoverflow in text format rather than a link to a next site. It would then have a better chance of someone answering it

Comment: Try this: `document.getElementById('Africa-Tree-Div').style.display = "block";` ID of the element is without `#`.

Answer (score 1):

For making overlay items, try positioning them by using the `position: fixed` attribute. Since the a-frame canvas is taking up the whole screen, you should "fix" them over the canvas.

---

When using `getElementById` you don't have to use the `#` character.

When using `document.querySelector` you should use

- `.` for classes
- `#` for id's

---

Furthermore, your CSS selector is `#Africa-Tree` while the div is `#Africa-Tree-Div`.

Comment: Hm doesn’t seem to be working on mobile though, I’m not seeing anything pop up when the tree is clicked

Comment: throw `cursor="rayOrigin: mouse` on the `<a-scene>` and get rid of the cursor entity - https://glitch.com/edit/#!/well-lathe?path=index.html:47:57 - works on android 7.1

Comment: @JohnAdegbuji let me know if my glitch is working for you

Comment: Nope. It works on everything but iPhone. I keep tapping the tree but nothing shows up